# Is there a way to nest the TODAY() function into an external cell reference in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

One of the daily repetitive tasks that my team handles requires using an excel template to format and upload rate indices to our system.

The 9 cells that contain the rates are currently set up as individual outside cell references. The format of the cell formulas are: ='S:\Ext1\Ext2[RATESHEET 02-02-2023.xlsx]RateName'!$C$7

The file being referenced in [RATESHEET 02-02-2023.xlsx] is updated every day with a new file and the current date. Right now, a member of the team has to go in daily and update each reference cell formula with today's date. I want this to update without going in to every cell.

I have three possibilities that seem plausible, but I can't seem to search correctly to figure out if any of these are possible in Excel.

Best case scenario, I would love to nest the function TEXT(TODAY(), "mm-dd-yyyy") into the reference formula and have each reference cell update with the daily date every time the file is opened.

Second best, I considered that all of the cells could reference a dummy cell that has the text/today function already in it.

Third best idea is to provide a user prompt to enter the date in that format, and have it update the cells from there.

Excel wizards, please let me know if there is any good way to accomplish this task.

Comment: You would use INDIRECT with the concatenated string, but realize that using INDIRECT requires the target workbook be open.

Comment: Awesome. I was able to figure it out using INDIRECT. Thank you for the bump!